# Creating charts from input data in html tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found many plugins based on jquery and javascript which generate charts from the tables but all the table values are hard-coded. But my table values are inputs from the user and I need to generate the charts on the fly. Any idea how I can do this?

Currently I am using canvasjs.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<title>My Chart</title>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-VAvG3sHdS5LqTT+5A/aeq/bZGa/Uj04xKxY8KM/w9EE="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function hello() {

//Better to construct options first and then pass it as a parameter
  var options = {
    title: {
        text: "My Chart"
    },
            animationEnabled: true,
    data: [
    {
        type: "column", //change it to line, area, bar, pie, etc
        dataPoints: [
            { x:25, y: 10 },
            { x: 20, y: 11 },
            { x: 30, y: 14 },
            { x: 40, y: 16 },
            { x: 50, y: 19 },
            { x: 60, y: 15 },
            { x: 70, y: 12 },
            { x: 80, y: 10 }
        ]
    }
    ]
};

$("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart(options);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Then I tried using `document.getElementById()` to get the variable value from the input and assigning it to the variable in the `hello()` function. But it is giving the error.

HELP!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

**Jquery**

```
var test = $('#inputValue').val()
```

**javascript**

```
var test = document.getElementById("inputValue").value;
```

or you can show me the error for try to help

Comment: Now I added this to the code. `<input type="number" id="inputValue" value=20 onclick="hello()">`

Comment: `var test = document.getElementById("inputValue").value;`

Comment: and `x:test` this should work according to the logic. But it does not invoke the `hello()` function when I click the text field. Then it generates the graph but does not consider the field which has been assigned to `test`.

Comment: you can try with another events "change" or bind?

Comment: I will try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Prathamesh,

You can use `document.getElementById("inputValue").value` and `document.getElementById("buttonID").onclick` if you like to add dataPoint on-click of button. Or `document.getElementById("inputValue").onchange`if you like to add on change of value.

Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/fLwvhx3f/) where values are added on click of button.